# django python form to submit, delete row from database and refresh page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am newbie in Django and I would appreciate if someone can help me about this problem.

I have a database in backend with 100 rows of users information. 
Name, surname, phone number.

The database is visible on Home page template and if you choose one of this names you can donate something to this person.

When you click on submit button will lead you to new ajax window where you input your data and then submit.

Then I got your message on email.

My questions is how to do at the same time to confirm (submit) and delete row from database (person from database) and then to refresh page ?
Meaning, when you submit form then function should delete person from Home page at once and have to  refresh page so you can see another person ?

Here is the code.
I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks to all.

**views.py**

```html
def about(request):
    context = {
        'num_toys': '1',
    }
    return render(request, 'about.html')  # , context=context


def couses(request):
    db_queryset = Children.objects.all()
    context = {'child': db_queryset}

    return render(request, 'couses.html', context=context)


class ChildrenListView(ListView):
    model = Children
    context_object_name = 'child'


class ChildrenCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Children
    form_class = ChildrenForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('children_changelist')


class ChildrenUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Children
    form_class = ChildrenForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('children_changelist')


class ChildrenDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Children
    form_class = ChildrenForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('children_detail')
```

**children_detail.html**

```html
      



      
           <!-- Start contact form area -->
     <div class="couses">  
        <section class="contact-form-area pb-60 pt-90">
   <div class="couses">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Start section title -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="section-title text-center">
       <h2>Donate <span> {{ children.toy }} </span> to <span>{{ children.name }}</span> who is <span>{{children.date }} old</span></h2>
                            <img src="static/children/img/title-bottom.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End section title -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="mail.php">
                                <div class="form-fields">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-fields">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-fields last">
                                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="message-fields">
                                    <label for="mess">Message</label>
                                    <textarea name="mess" id="mess" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-button">
                                    <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
                                    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            
                            <p class="form-messege"></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
   </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I'm wrong but I understand that you want to do two actions.

In your code I can see that you have forms and class-based Views. Maybe you need to override the function form_valid to do the operations you need when you submit.

Check this website http://ccbv.co.uk there you will find the details of the views.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I will check the link. Yes, I have to add some code but I am not sure which one just to delete and refresh page, cause I don't want to repeat the person from database. So , once you submit, then it needs to delete from template and from database.

Comment: Maybe if you create a new boolean field with False default value in your model of person in database and when you submit, change the value of that field to True, then when you refresh the page in your queryset of your ListView only get the persons with the false value on the new field

Comment: Hmm.. interesting ... I will try it. If am not succeed with delete from database, then I have to find a way at least to hide from Home page

Comment: If you delete an object of your model Children then when you redirect to your ListView of Children, it should not appear

Answer (score 0):

On click of submit hit the url & process your message on email part first and then you can delete the person from database by filtering out object of that particular person with whatever primary key you have for that table by writing a query in your view. and then render the remaining data of that table to your template on which you are Redirecting from your on submit click.

From above conversation what i understood that you don't want delete that person from database boolean field would be great option rather you want to save the message that has been sent from email by this way you can do both at the same time. you have the message saved in your database and from empty message data can render those user on template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Have you any clue about code, just any sample ? I am trying to find something but I think am going in circle

Comment: for email and class based views you can take help from these tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/beginners-guide/1.11/  . this will definitely clear things out for you.